# Finding big-O complexity. of three algorithms

Tags: java, performance, big-o

I am trying to find the the time complexity of the following algorithm.

From what i can see the first two loops in alg1 are **n^2** however I'm not sure what running time the loop in alg2 is then.

```
public class algo {




public static int alg1(int[] A, int n) {
    int l = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i <= n-1; i++) {
        for (int j = i+1; j <= n-1 ; j++) {
           if(alg2(A,i,j) && j-i > l) {
               l = j-i+1;
           }
        }
    }

    return l;

}

private static boolean alg2(int[] A,int i, int j) {
    if(i==j) {
        return true;
    }

    for (int k = i; k <= j-1; k++) {
        if(A[k] != A[k+1]) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`alg2` is O(n)

`alg1` since it has `alg2` inside the inner for loop so it should be O(n^2 * n) = O(n^3). If you want to prove it:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct the first Alg1 has time complexity of O(n^2). The second function Alg2 has time complexity of O(n) because the performance of the algorithm will grow linearly in proportion to its input size. You only have one for loop and you are not applying D&C technique anywhere in that code.

Comment: Since alg1 calls alg2, its complexity includes alg2's complexity as well.